# Algorithm Environment

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I want to write an algorithm into my paper but it is just a pseudocode and none of the fancy if-then loops etc. Instead, I want it to look something like Algorithm 11.1 here:

[image]

What environment should I use to make that happen?

Comment: The font used there is just a sans serif font. You can use inside the environment `\sffamily` or you can use just for a piece of text `\textsf{}`.

Comment: The environment just looks like an ordinary `enumerate` with a different choice of font.

Comment: This does not need any package for algorithms. If you would like to use one, just click on the tag you used for your question. The document is done in TeX and the authors E-Mail-address is on the last page. If you suspect something special in his code, send him a friendly message to share that algorithm with you.

Comment: Yeah, as others noted, it appears to be an `enumerate` with sans serif font. The beginning portion appears to simply be a theorem-like environment (perhaps using amsthm and lines like `\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}[section]` or something similar?)...